# Geowebcache pre-seed creates white and black tiles

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache, wmts, image-pyramids

I have published Arial photo on GeoServer using ImagePyramid technique. I have created custom gridset for it.
I have created cached tiles using geoWebcache pre-seeding. When I am accessing it in Qgis using WMTS, from zoom level 01 to 09 its seems correct. but after zoom level 09 on somewhere, I found black and white tiles.
[image]
    But When I am accessing it on QGIS using WMS (tiled=true). At the same zoom level, it seems correct. [image]

Can anybody suggest why GWC creates white and black tiles and how to fix it?

Debug log :

> 2018-07-09 10:35:25,028 INFO [org.geoserver.wms] -  Request: getMap
>     Angle = 0.0     BaseUrl = http://localhost:8080/geoserver/  Bbox =
>   SRSEnvelope[137392.943896347 : 138088.0333557299, 123511.53727982522 :
>   124206.62673920812]   BgColor = java.awt.Color[r=255,g=255,b=255]     Buffer = 0  CQLFilter = null    Crs = PROJCS["TM75 / Irish Grid",
>   GEOGCS["TM75", 
>       DATUM["Geodetic Datum of 1965", 
>         SPHEROID["Airy Modified 1849", 6377340.189, 299.3249646, AUTHORITY["EPSG","7002"]], 
>         TOWGS84[482.5, -130.6, 564.6, -1.042, -0.214, -0.631, 8.15], 
>         AUTHORITY["EPSG","6300"]], 
>       PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0, AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]], 
>       UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295], 
>       AXIS["Geodetic longitude", EAST], 
>       AXIS["Geodetic latitude", NORTH], 
>       AUTHORITY["EPSG","4300"]],    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator", AUTHORITY["EPSG","9807"]],    PARAMETER["central_meridian", -8.0],
>   PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin", 53.5],    PARAMETER["scale_factor",
>   1.000035],    PARAMETER["false_easting", 200000.0],    PARAMETER["false_northing", 250000.0],    UNIT["m", 1.0],
>   AXIS["Easting", EAST],    AXIS["Northing", NORTH],
>   AUTHORITY["EPSG","29903"]]    Elevation = []  Env = {}    Exceptions =
>   SE_XML    FeatureId = null    FeatureVersion = null   Filter = null
>     Filters = null  Format = image/jpeg     FormatOptions = {}  Get = true
>     Height = 1024   Interpolations = []     Layers =
>   [org.geoserver.wms.MapLayerInfo@edba3cf7]     MaxFeatures = null  Palette
>   = null    RawKvp = {FORMAT=image/jpeg, STYLES=raster, WIDTH=1024, HEIGHT=1024, LAYERS=New_IrelandLimerick:Ireland_Limerick_New,
>   EXCEPTIONS=SE_XML, GWC_SEED_INTERCEPT=true, REQUEST=GetMap,
>   SRS=EPSG:29903,
>   BBOX=137392.943896347,123511.53727982522,138088.0333557299,124206.62673920812, VERSION=1.1.1, SERVICE=WMS, TRANSPARENT=true}  RemoteOwsType = null
>     RemoteOwsURL = null     Request = GetMap    RequestCharset = UTF-8
>     ScaleMethod = null  Sld = null  SldBody = null  SldVersion = null
>     SortBy = null   SortByArrays = null     SRS = EPSG:29903    StartIndex =
>   null  StyleBody = null    StyleFormat = sld   Styles = [StyleImpl[
>   name=raster]]     StyleUrl = null     StyleVersion = null     Tiled = false
>     TilesOrigin = null  Time = []   Transparent = true  ValidateSchema =
>   false     Version = 1.1.1     ViewParams = null   Width = 1024
>   2018-07-09 10:35:25,059 DEBUG [org.geoserver.gwc.layer] - --> GWC
>   Seeder Thread-11 submitting getMap request for meta grid location
>   [196, 72, 9] on org.geoserver.gwc.layer.GeoServerMetaTile@561daeb8
>   2018-07-09 10:35:25,059 INFO [org.geoserver.wms] -  Request:
>   getServiceInfo 2018-07-09 10:35:25,059 DEBUG [org.geoserver.ows] -
>   Getting layers and styles from LAYERS and STYLES 2018-07-09
>   10:35:25,059 DEBUG [org.geoserver.ows] - establishing raster style for
>   New_layer:RasterData 2018-07-09 10:35:25,059 DEBUG [org.geoserver.wms]
>   - setting up map 2018-07-09 10:35:25,059 DEBUG [org.geoserver.wms.map] - setting up 1024x1024 image 2018-07-09 10:35:25,059 TRACE [org.geoserver.jai] - Recycling tile hit on type:1, banks: 786,432,
>   arrayLength: {3}

Comment: those don't look like whole tiles - do you have overlapping granules in your pyramid?

Comment: No, I haven't added overlapping granules in the pyramid.

Comment: I'm with Ian on this one - this doesn't look like black/white tiles, it looks like an overlap issue (So GeoServer side). To help debug it, it may be worth looking at your GeoServer logs to see what requests the GWC is actually making to create those tiles. You can debug from there.

Comment: Thanks to all. OKay, I am trying to debug and find requests the GWC is actually making to create those tiles.

Comment: I am trying to debug it, but I haven't found such type of information. I have added debug log in the Question. Can you help me to find the correct information and how to fix it?

Comment: To investigate whether there's a problem with certain tiles, you could try loading the ImagePyramid layer shapefiles (0.shp, 1.shp, 2.shp etc.) one-at-a-time into QGIS. With some transparency applied, place the shapefiles on top of your imagery layer. View the attributes of the shape that most aligns with the problem areas to get the problem tile's name/folder location. Then open that tile with any image software/review its size compared to "good" tiles etc. You may need to "retile" those if they're corrupt.

Comment: Hi @sumantsingh, did you manage to fix that error ? (and do you remember how you did it?)